# Create a table from full outer join query

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables namely :- `TDM` & `AccountMaster`. Both are having three equal columns and I have to create a table retrieving all the rows from `TDM-table` joining the three columns,i.e. `FD_BRANCH,FD_CUSTCODE & PRODUCTID.`

while creating table through select into clause  I get an error

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'FD_BRANCH' in table 'acty' is specified more than once.

Please find the following query from which I want to create a table which as per my requirement :-

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT FD_BRANCH,FD_CUSTCODE,PRODUCTID FROM TDM 
GROUP BY FD_BRANCH,FD_CUSTCODE,PRODUCTID) A full OUTER JOIN AccountMaster B 
ON( A.FD_BRANCH=B.FD_BRANCH AND A.FD_CUSTCODE=B.FD_CUSTCODE AND 
A.PRODUCTID=B.PRODUCTID)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. If you want your `select into` to work, column names have to be unique. You can do this by giving them an alias. You say "Column name 'FD_BRANCH' in table 'acty' is specified more than once." Where is the table `acty`?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Change your select to get only the fields you need from one of the 2 tables.

```
Select  A.*
FROM    (
```

or

```
Select  B.FD_BRANCH,
        B.FD_CUSTCODE,
        B.PRODUCTID
FROM    (
```

FULL OUTER JOIN combines the 2 sets of columns from both queries so you end up with at least 6 columns.  Even though they're from different tables or aliases the columns names are the same.